# Utilizing ICommand in WPF -- Command returning null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I am working on a sample ViewModel in WPF and I am currently binding 3 textboxes in the View to `Id`, `FirstName`, and `LastName`.  I then have a button click event in the xaml.cs file that executes a method that updates the sample database table.  I am trying to wrap my head around MVVM and WPF.  I want to take away the button click event and bind to a Command instead. I am using Linq to Sql for the db connection.

When I am debugging the code everything is returning null. Am I on the right path?

Thanks!

Here is part of the VM (I didnt want to post all the code.)

```
public class People
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

private People mPeople = null;
private Guid mId = Guid.empty;

public People people
{
    get {return mPeople;}
    set {mPeople = value; OnPropertyChanged("people");}
}


public overide void Refresh()    
{      
    Using (DatabaseDataContext dc = new DatabaseDataContext())      
    {
        mId = CurrentUser.Identity;

        var query = from person in dc.PeopleTables 
            where person.PId = mId
            select new People()
            {
                Id = person.PId,
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                LastName = person.LastName
            };

        mPeople = query.First();
    }
}
```

In the VM here is what I am trying with the Commands

```
private RelayCommand mUserUpdate = null;

public ICommand UserUpdate
{
    get
    {
        if(mUserUpdate == null) mUserUpdate = new RelayCommand(p => UpdateUser(p));
        return mUserUpdate;
    }
}

private void UpdateUser(object parameter)
{
    People pe = parameter as People;
    UpdateUser(pe.Id, pe.FirstName, pe.LastName);
}

public static void UpdateUser(Guid Id, string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    DatabaseDataContext DC = new DatabaseDatacontext();

    var User = (from c in DC.GetTable<PeopleTable>()
                where c.PId = mId
            select c).SingleOrDefault();

    if (User == null
    {
        //Do my inserts here 
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            User.Id = Id;
        User.FirstName = FirstName;
        User.LastName = LastName;

        DC.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my click event I was using

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserViewModel.UpdateUser(txtId.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
}
```

---

Yea, I took out the click event and replaced it with

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=UserUpdate}"/>
```

I am binding the textboxes like this

```
<TextBox Width="250" Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/> 
</StackPanel> 
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0"> 
<Label Content="First Name:" Margin="0,0,4,0"/> 
<TextBox Width="250" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/> 
</StackPanel> 
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0"> 
<Label Content="Last Name:" Margin="35,0,4,0"/> 
<TextBox Width="250" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
```

Comment: Can we see your xaml code? Specially the part where you set the Command property on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the UpdateUser Method

```
Private void UpdateUser(object obj)
{
    UpdateUser(Id, FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Commands are intended to `replace` the `Click` event handler of buttons.

You should remove the event handler and do

```
<Button Command="{Binding UserUpdate}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set the command parameter:

```
<Button Command="{Binding UserUpdate}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedUser}"/>
```

If "SelectedUser" comes from your VM and not the current UI you don't need the parameter. Just get the reference to the user intance you want to modify in your VM.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands your code isn't working because you're expecting a parameter of type Person to be passed the command which isn't possible (I think).

Your view model needs to look like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel : *INotifyPropertyChanged base class here*
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        UpdatePersonCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateUser);
    }

    public Guid Id {get{ return _id;} { set _id = Id; RaisePropertyChanged("Id"); }
    public string FirstName { ... same }
    public string LastName { ... same }

    public ICommand UpdatePersonCommand {get; private set;}

    private void UpdateUser()
    {
        UpdateUser(Id, FirstName, LastName);
    }

    private void UpdateUser(Guid Id, string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        DatabaseDataContext DC = new DatabaseDatacontext();
        ...
    }

}
```